# How to access Solr data from R script?

Tags: r, solr

Is there a R package that simplify access to the data stored into Apache Solr server? 
I know that Solr has a REST-like API, and R has a `RCurl` package that provide http/https communication, but such communication is not as simple as we would like. 
Please help me find a way to simplify the Solr - R interaction.
Thanks.

Comment: When asking a question about an API, it's best to link to said API. Have you searched on GitHub for an existing wrapper? If someone hasn't already written a package, do you want advice on how to wrap an API from R or is that beyond your skillset?

Comment: "Please help me find a way to simplify the Solr - R interaction." - What do you want to simplify? What is the specific problem you are having?

Comment: I am very late to the game, but I am working on an R pkg for interacting with solr endpoints here https://github.com/ropensci/solr